# How to fetch data in retrofit 2 using query parameters in your Url?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a URL for example `www.fetchdata123.com/myservice.php?CityId=5`
and want to fetch data on behave of CityId using

```
@GET("my_service.php?")
 Call<List<Employees>> GetEmployees(@Query("CityId")  String CityId);
```

How to get the Employees data using that particular CityId.

Comment: please do specify the error that you face

Comment: Share your implementation of Retrofit interface

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference. this is the error i am recieving

Comment: String CityId= "300";                                        
 public void fetch_information(String CityId)
    {                                                           ApiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(Api.class);
        Call<List<Client>> call = ApiInterface.GetClients(CityId);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Client>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Client>> call, Response<List<Client>> response) {
                Clients = response.body();                              prepareClientsData();}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having en extra **`?`** ,Change your code like this

```
 @GET("my_service")
 Call<List<Employees>> GetEmployees(@Query("CityId")  String CityId);
```

while using `@Query`, **`?`** is automatically appended